# UIContainerView embed AVPlayerViewController

Tags: swift, avplayer, tvos, uicontainerview

When trying to use a `UIContainerView` to embed a `AVPlayerViewController` the video in the `AVPlayer` never seems to be able to play video or become focusable.

Has anyone been able to make this work? Could you provide a sample project of this working?

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

    var player: AVPlayer?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        print(#function)
        self.player?.play()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        // Do any additional setup before displaying the view
        print(#function)
        self.player?.play()
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        print(#function)
        if let playerCntrl = segue.destinationViewController as? AVPlayerViewController {
            let url = NSURL(string: "https://devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net/streaming/examples/bipbop_16x9/bipbop_16x9_variant.m3u8")
            playerCntrl.player = url.flatMap({ AVPlayer(URL: $0) })
            self.player = playerCntrl.player
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I've updated the question with the `UIViewController` code. The rest of the layout occurs in storyboard.